# Align vertices to X-axis

Tags: modeling

I was wondering if there are any easy ways in Blender apart from grabbing individual vertices to bring all the vertices in the picture down so they perfectly aligned on the x-axis?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Scale with <kbd>S</kbd> then press <kbd>X</kbd> and then <kbd>0</kbd>. This will bring all of your vertices into the middle and all aligned. This works with all axis: X, Y, Z.